# Loading Indicator does not appear when the radio button is chosen and the 'add' button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Rails4 version.
Here are the choices that I need to make:

[image]

When I do my choice for the first time and click the 'Add' button, the loading indicator doesn't appear. When I do it second time and click the 'Add' button the loading indicator appears and working fine. I am not really good with javascript, so I do not really know how to trigger the loading indicator to appear at first attempt. Here is my code:

My VIEW file:

```
<div id="loading-indicator" style="display:none">
 <%=" Wait..."%><%= image_tag("/images/ajax-loader-8.gif", :id => "loading-indicator") %>
</div>
```

My CSS file:

```
#loading-indicator {
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  }
```

My 'create.js' file:

```
$(document) 

.ajaxStart(function() {


$('#loading-indicator').show();// show on any Ajax event.
$("#notice").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'layouts/flash' , 
:locals => {   :flash => flash }).html_safe %>").hide();
})
.ajaxStop(function() {

$("#notice").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'layouts/flash' , 
:locals => { :flash => flash }).html_safe %>").show();
$('#loading-indicator').hide(); // hide it when it is done.

});

$("#transaction_paypal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'trans')%>");
```

Thank you.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle please, so that we can help you easier finding the problem

Comment: look here http://jsfiddle.net/ put in youre code click save, then post the url

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following lines of js to my application.js file:

```
$(document) 

.ajaxStart(function() {


$('#loading-indicator').show();// show on any Ajax event.

})
.ajaxStop(function() {


$('#loading-indicator').hide(); // hide it when it is done.


});
```